# Removing .html from all url filenames using app.yaml for go runtime

Tags: google-app-engine, webpack-dev-server, app.yaml

I am trying to find a guide or some help on how to remove the .html from all url filenames using the app.yaml for go runtime on google app engine. I find the information on Google help docs on how to use app.yaml quite confusing if honest.

I have about 350 .html files over about 4 folders. My app.yaml file is in the root.

If it was a .htaccess file I am trying to do the equivalent of something like the below. Any ideas or tips?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

If I was to squeeze the ask further I would want to also have this set up so when I am using Webpack dev server and build I can also have a consistent usage / experience (i.e. works with no .html ending on the url) but that may be pushing the question for now and if honest I've not researched that one much at the moment.

Comment: Are those html files static assets?

Comment: Yes they are static files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, at least in GAE, you aren't *removing* the `.html` suffix, but rather *adding* it to the requested path to obtain the name of the static asset to serve (I'm assuming you actual asset files do have the `.html` suffix in their name).

It might be possible, depending on how you structure the namespace of your static assets.

If a subset (or all) of your `.html` files could be matched by a single regex pattern on the file path/name (other than the `.html` suffix) which doesn't match other static assets then it's easy, you just need 2 handler statements. Assuming below that the static files are in a `static` directory of your app, adjust as needed.

The first handler statement would serve the requests with the `.html` suffix, to prevent getting 404s for them (otherwise they would be translated to something like  `/path/file.html.html`, which probably isn't how you named your assets)

```
- url: /(<your_pattern>\.html)$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/<your_pattern>\.html$
```

The 2nd statement would be the one "appending" the `.html` suffix to the requested path and serving the respective asset file (if it exists, or 404 if not):

```
- url: /(<your_pattern>)$
  static_files: static/\1.html
  upload: static/<your_pattern>\.html$
```

An actual example, let's say your `.html` files would be requested as `/some/path/<file>.html` and you'd like them to also be accessible as `/some/path/<file>`. Then you'd have these handler statements:

```
# this serves your static/some/path/<file>.html asset as /some/path/<file>.html
- url: /(some/path/.*\.html)$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/some/path/.*\.html$

# this serves your static/some/path/<file>.html asset as /some/path/<file>
- url: /(some/path/.*)$
  static_files: static/\1.html
  upload: static/some/path/.*\.html$
```

If you have multiple such subsets you'd just add similar 2 statements for each of them. But this doesn't scale if you have many such subsets.

If you don't have such pattern (or if you have too many subsets) it may be more difficult. A single pair of statements with the 2nd having a blind/catch-all handler pattern would still work for the static `.html` files:

```
- url: /(.*\.html)$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/.*\.html$

# catch-all pattern
- url: /(.*)$
  static_files: static/\1.html
  upload: static/.*\.html$
```

But this may likely interfere with any other static files and with your app's dynamic handlers (if you have any). To avoid that you'd need **all** of those to be identifiable by more specific pattern(s) and you'd have to place the handler statement(s) for them **above** the catch-all one.